# Exception of Adding a new value on Regedit

Tags: c#, exception, regedit, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I am trying to add a Value into this path but It is giving an Exception:

> UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled.

**My snippet**

```
    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     RegistryKey Localuser= Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Winlogon");
     Localuser.SetValue("DefaultPassword","Password35");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to set the registry value of the local machine's key. You need administrator's right to do that. You should compile the program and run it as administrator.

If you need to make it run in debug mode, try the solution from this [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/585dcb31-1af7-460e-ad0a-8e6fffc37bed/registrykeysetvalue-throws-unauthorizedaccessexception?forum=csharplanguage).

Another thing to take note: Make sure you call the function specifying it writable

```
RegistryKey Localuser= Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(
    "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Winlogon",
    true);
```